# Ant crawling on a curve at unit speed

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, curves

For the longest time I've been puzzled by a problem of my own creation:

Suppose an ant crawls along a curve parametrized by the functions $x(t), y(t)$. Does there exist a function $s(t)$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ such that the ant, with position at time t $(x(s(t)), y(s(t)))$, crawls at constant unit speed? In other words, does there exist $s(t)$ such that the magnitude of the ant's instantaneous velocity $||v(s(t))||=1$ always?

The way I've gone about this so far is by deriving a differential equation from the condition $||v(s(t))||=1$,
$$||v(s(t)||=\sqrt{x'(s(t))^2s'(t)^2+y'(s(t))^2s'(t)^2}=1$$
$$\Rightarrow s'(t)^2\bigl(x'(s(t))^2+y'(s(t))^2\bigr)=1,$$
but I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Perhaps I've overcomplicated it.

I'm interested to see what you all can remedy from this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does the curve have to be smooth?

Comment: This $s(t)$ is called the natural or arclength parameter, and it is equal to the length of the curve measured from some initial value $t=a$ to the current value. You can calculate it by using the arclength formula, but the integral often can not  be found explicitly, see [natural parametrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_curve#Length_and_natural_parametrization).